# ASP.net MVC Paging

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have textboxes loaded with data on my ASP.NET MVC page. If the user clicks the `Next` button I need to load the textboxes with the relevant data. Similarly I have `Next`, `Prev` and `Last` buttons for record navigation. I have no idea on how to implement this. If it is JQuery how I can implement it? How do I implement it in ASP.NET MVC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your model to implement a [PagedList](http://www.superexperttraining.com/blog/archive/2008/09/18/asp-net-mvc-tip-44-create-a-pager-html-helper.aspx) and then bind the each item in the result to a textbox, this can be done in Ajax using Jquery too

Comment: I tried this approach and not working for me. I doubt whether I did correctly. I would appreciate if you send some code samples to do this. Thanks !

Comment: I fixed the issue at my end and now it is working fine for me.

Answer (score 5):

The good news is that there is a complete example of this in the [Nerddinner ASP.NET MVC Walkthrough](http://aspnetmvcbook.s3.amazonaws.com/aspnetmvc-nerdinner_v1.pdf) (pg 118-127).

[image]
<sub>(source: [barnesandnoble.com](http://images.barnesandnoble.com/images/37260000/37268921.JPG))</sub>

I also recommend the book that this is the sample chapter of: *[Professional ASP.NET MVC 1.0](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470384611)* by Wrox Press.

Comment: I went through that paging chapter. They are listing certain number of records from database. My scenario is different. I have Results Page with some records listed. If the user selects a particular record I will take it to the edit page with data loaded in textboxes. In this page I have buttons prev,next,last,first through which the user can navigate other records of search results in Edit mode. Please let me know some solution for this ! Thanks !